# Use generated string as names of textBoxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to put the contents of a ton of textBoxes into a database and to make the code shorter i'm trying to use generated strings as names of the textboxes, but how can i apply this?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= 7; i2++)
    {
        string tbName = "textBox" + i.ToString() + i2.ToString();
        [buttonName].Text="someting";
    }
}
```

If this would work i could reduce my repetitive code a lot. How can i use the contents of a string as the name of a textBox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the instance of the textbox and then use it :

```
TextBox txtBox = FindControl(tbName) as TextBox;
if(txtBox !=null)
    txtBox.Text="someting";
```

But if the textBoxes are nested in the other controls, then you will need to recursively look in to every control to find the needed text box control explained at following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx

Comment: The textBoxes are inside some divs and a table, is this what you mean?

Comment: within other server side controls